# Adding views programmatically too slow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page that needs to be created dynamically. 
We have chosen to fill the page with frames and inputs from a list, but since they can become rather complex, we decided to make it programmatically, instead of putting them inside a ListView.

The problem is: When there are a lot of items to input, the page generation is very slow, and gives out the feeling that the app froze (sometimes it does freeze). 
Is there a way to create those views quickly enough that it won't keep the user waiting?

I have tried creating an empty page and adding the inputs inside a Task, so they wouldn't hurt UX, but that is still slow, and somethings crashes the app. 
All inputs are inside Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread.

Comment: `lot of items to input` What is *lots*? And can you add an example of how you are creating/adding the controls.

Comment: For each new view you add to your page, all layout is redesigned. You can try do the heavy work outside the main thread and when it's finished, you include it on your view container. Try to set the page name like `x:Name="pagContent"`, initialize the page with a `ActivityIndicator` runing and a `Label` "Loading..." inside a `StackLayout`, for example, and when your job finish, set the `pagContent.Content = yourLoadedView`.

Comment: @SushiHangover, lots varies, but it can go as _lots_ as 100 inputs

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, I tried doing exactly that. Even though the page ceased crashing, the load is still very slow. I tried not loading any labels, to see if the load time changed, but to no avail.

Comment: So you have to share a contexted sample code, then we can see if there are a better way to go.